# Konami code changing every color

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Okay I want to change my websites colors on the press of a button. So i have this code:

```
  $( window ).konami({
    code : [38,38], // up up 
    cheat: function() {

        $('*').filter(function() {
          var match = 'rgb(255, 165, 0)'; // match background-color: black
          /*
              true = keep this element in our wrapped set
              false = remove this element from our wrapped set
                                                               */
          return ( $(this).css('color') == match );

      }).css('color', 'purple'); // change background color of all black spans

    }
});
```

Now the problem is I want to add bunch of other attributes like background-color, border-color and even active and hover color - though these two might be problematic with this code snippet I think.

Any help adding named attributes to the fray is welcomed - as I'm not an javascript expert by no means.

Also bonus question my webpage is on AngularJS and when I used this konami code, it seems to only work on colors that are currently on display. So on different pages I would have to enter the keys again. Any simple workaround or I gotta deal with it?

Comment: [Read the doc](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) and use a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) or [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)

Comment: Easiest way is to use the code to add a class to the body tag. Then just scope your CSS. As for the bonus question... Yes.. Use a cookie.

Comment: @SeanStopnik I can't quite fathom what do you mean by adding a class to body tag and then scoping css, or how that helps